# Internet Explorer CSS or JS issue causing preloader to stay up and owl carousel to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer CSS or JS issue causing preloader to stay up and owl carousel to not work. I've test jquery and it is working.

The page is under day4days.org/test.html

Comment: so ... any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at their issues on github: 
https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues
Also if you expect help, you really need to make a simple example on jsbin.com . The link you sent is a whole web page.

Comment: Thank you for the note. The console did have Internet explorer errors. Jquery is not loading for some reason.

Comment: Due to what Internet Explorer calls a syntax error in the script to call jquery SCRIPT1002: Syntax error